# Validate a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not that good with regular expressions...

I need a JavaScript regular expression that will do the following:

1. The string can contain letters (upper **and** lower case), but not punctuations such as éàïç...
2. The string can contain numbers (0..9) anywhere in the string, **except** on the first position.
3. The string can contain underscores (_).

Valid strings:

- foo
- foo1
- foo_bar
- fooBar

Invalid strings:

- 1foo --> number as first character
- foo bar --> space
- föo --> punctuation ö

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS identifier validator? Although some validation rules are missing, this comes very close.

Comment: Nah it's for a naming system. These are my rules to "simplify" readability of those names.

Comment: Ah OK. Regardless, posted an answer :) Hope that helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This regex should do what you need:

```
/^[a-z_]+[\w]*$/i
```

Use it as follows:

```
var match = /^[a-z_]+[\w]*$/i.test(string);
```

Some explanation:

```
/      : start of JavaScript regex pattern
^      : start of string
[a-z_] : only alphabetic characters or underscore
+      : one or more
[\w]   : any word-character (aplhanumeric and the underscore)
*      : zero or more
$      : end of string
/      : end of JavaScript regex pattern
i      : case insensitive modifier
```

To learn more about regular expressions, you may find [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info) useful.

Comment: Just needs an underscore in the [a-z]: `[a-z_]`

Comment: Yes, if the underscore may appear anywhere, then the `[a-z]` should indeed be `[a-z_]`. Hmm, actually, you're right he didn't explicitly forbid the underscore in the front. Updated answer.